# How to scrape an Angular element

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm trying to scrape a web page built in Angular.  The format of the information I'm after looks like this:

```
<mat-row class="mat-row ng-star-inserted" role="row">
    <mat-cell class="mat-cell cdk-column-Players mat-column-Players ng-star-inserted" role="gridcell">
        <a href="users/205101">Federer, Roger</a>
    </mat-cell>
</mat-row>
```

I'd like to get the name in the link, "Federer, Roger", so I tried:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(SITE))
doc.css('mat-row')
```

And get nothing back.

I also tried copying the full XPath from the Chrome browser tools using:

```
doc.xpath("//html/body/usq-club-locker-app/usq-team-profile/usq-profile/section/div/div[4]/mat-card/mat-tab-group/div/mat-tab-body[4]/div/div/div/mat-table/mat-row[1]/mat-cell[1]")
```

but also got no results back.

How can I tell Nokogiri to find all `mat-row` elements with a specified class?

Comment: Using your snippet as a string, and doing `Nokogiri::HTML(str).css('mat-row')`, I'm getting your one element (and more specifically, `doc.css('mat-row mat-cell a').map(&:text)` is getting me `["Federer, Roger"]`). Please construct a [example] that demonstrates you can't access what you are trying to access. Nevertheless, you should probably use `Nokogiri::XML` for XML data, not `Nokogiri::HTML`.

Comment: Maybe the content you are trying to scrape is being loaded with a xhr request after the page loaded? Try dumping the document your script gets to a file and check if the data you need is there.

Comment: I can't duplicate the problem. "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" will help us help you. Don't copy XPath from a browser. Browsers are pathologically helpful and will wet themselves trying to make you happy. OK, not that helpful. They munge the HTML being presented so it looks good on the screen but it's not necessarily what the server sent. Use `wget` or `curl` or `httparty` or `nokogiri` at the command-line and look at what they get as they're your friends.